# Error with cookie that stores a javascript variable to be read with php

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I been working in a php/javascript quiz, and in order to store a variable located in a script that is Quiz.score, I have created a cookie that it purpose is, when test ended and score is shown, it would save the data to read it in php and send it to a mysql server's table, the cookie's structure is the following:

createCookie.js

```js
// Creating a cookie after the document is ready 
$(document).ready(function() {
  createCookie("scr", Quiz.score, "10");
});
// Function to create the cookie 
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires;
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  } else {
    expires = "";
  }
  document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" +
    escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

But when I try to request for the cookie by specifying the name, in the following code:

rvnqended.php

```
<?php 
    echo $_COOKIE["scr"]; 
?> 
<script src="js/createCookie.js"></script>
```

It gives me the following error:

Notice: Undefined index: scr in C:\xampp\htdocs\uttn\rvnqended.php on line 2

Also when I use the console it shows the following error:
createCookie.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at createCookie.js:2

In sources shows the following text:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try check cookie is existed on browser ?

Comment: WHEN do you try to access the scr cookie? - you first have to load the page into the browser and then ajax/load the php that accesses the scr cookie. You are not showing where and when you call rvnqended.php

Comment: I just checked that and no, there is no cookie stored in my browser, also I just found another error in this line " $(document).ready(function() { " the console's browser shows me this  : createCookie.js:2 Uncaught Reference and in Sources shows me thie  Error: $ is not defined
    at createCookie.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You have included your jQuery javascript file before calling this function?

Comment: As long as I researched, I haven't seen that people in tutorials used jQuery so i haven't included it neither, but it works for them, but can't undestand why does it not work for me